# Prove that $G$ or $\bar G$ must be nonplanar if G has 11 vertices.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, graph-theory, proof-writing, planar-graphs

The exact problem is the following: "Let G be a graph with 11 vertices. Prove that $G$ or $\bar G$ must be nonplanar.

I went to my professor to discuss the proof, but she said it didn't quite work, that something was "off" about it. The following is the proof I presented:

Let $G$ be a graph with 11 vertices. It is clear that $\lvert{E(G)}\rvert$+$\lvert{E(\bar G)}\rvert$=$\lvert{E(K_{11})}\rvert$=$55$.

Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that both $G$ and $\bar G$ are nonplanar. Then $$\lvert{E(G)}\rvert+\lvert{E(\bar G)}\rvert \le (3\lvert{V(G)}\rvert-6)+(3\lvert{V(\bar G)}\rvert-6)=54. \Rightarrow\Leftarrow$$ 
Therefore, either $G$ or $\bar G$ is nonplanar.

So, where exactly does this proof fail? Any tips on the aesthetics of the proof would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect there's a way to prove that a graph with 11 nodes and 28 edges contains $K_5$.

Comment: The opposite of "$G$ and $\bar G$ is nonplanar" is *not* "one of $G$ and $\bar G$ is nonplanar", but "either $G$ of $\bar G$ *or both* are planar". So you see the problem is that you have not excluded that both are planar. For a proof by contradiction one usually would assume both as planar and show that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the $K_{11}$ has $55$ edges. Now lets form $G$ with $27$ edges: As you already wrote for a triangulation we have $3 V(G) - 6 = 27$ edges. But for $\overline{G}$ we have 28 edges left. Thus there is one edge that will violate the planarity of the triangulation in $\overline{G}$.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this similar proof. However, it does not really answer the question as to where the proof I have presented fails. Thank you though.

Comment: As M. Winter in the comments to you question suggests. I also would agree that a classical contradiction proof would assume both $G$ and $\overline{G}$ to be planar. Then similarly as in my setting, you show that at lest one graph can not be planar.